# Does the subtraction of strictly increased and strictly decreased function has only one zero (at most)?

Tags: roots, monotone-functions

I have the following expression:

$y(x)=f(x)-g(x)$

$f(x)$ is positive and strictly **increased** at the interval $x->[0 \ x_0]$

$g(x)$ is positive and strictly **decreased** at the interval $x->[0 \ x_0]$

Can I say or prove that $y(x)$ has at the most one zero?

Comment: If $g(x)$ is decreasing, $h(x)=-g(x)$ is increasing, thus $y(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ is an increasing function and what you claim is true.

Comment: Montonically increasing means $f(x) \leq f(y)$ for $x \leq y$. Unless you change montonically increasing/decreasing  to strictly increasing/decreasing your result is obviously false. Take $f=g=1$.

Comment: As per Giovannis Barbarani's comment, are you sure you stated this correctly?

Comment: You probably meant $ f(x) + g(x) $, in which case I recommend you consider what happens for the functions  $ x $ and $ -x^3 $.

Comment: Thank, I didn't realize that monotonic actually means non-decreasing/increasing. I've changed everything to strictly. Now I guess the first answer is valid

Comment: @Jake Mirra, No actually it's $f(x)-g(x)$ which in this case $x- -x^3$ has only one zero at $x=0$ whereas the sum of the two yields three zeros.